# windows.onresize - prevent it from execution before the variable created

Tags: javascript, dom, dictionary, domdocument

hello i searched for an answer over the internet but i couldn't understand something. so i asked.

I will start with the script that i have the problem:

```
 window.onresize=function(){
     if(_UserMarkerNewPosition){               //_UserMarkerNewPosition is global and contains coordinates 
          _Map.panTo(_UserMarkerNewPosition); //_Map is global and contains the map object
     }
     else{
         _Map.panTo(_UserMarkerPosition);    //_UserMarkerPosition is global and contains coordinates
     }
  }
```

this piece of code works perfect for almost all situations except one! My application locate the user location. As you know browsers when a page try to access the location of users ask users to share their location or not. At this point came the error. If the user at the moment of browser question resize the window then javascript says **TypeError: _Map is Undifine**. This error is caused because at the time that the window is resizing the _Map is not created. So my question is how can i prevent this from happening?

**How can i stop window.onresize execution before the creation of _Map object??**

Any help will be appreciated. Many thanks for you time!

Comment: Then just add a sanity check to determine whether _Map is defined.

Comment: Also use setTimeout  to not trigger your function until the user stops resizing

Comment: @jack this is the only way?

Comment: @mplungjan yes but this will not work too because user can stop resizing and the _Map object will not be defined yet because user haven't allow the browser to shear his location yet. and this happen because i don't set the map if the user don't want to shear his location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if the variable is defined

```
window.onresize = function () {
    if (typeof _Map === "undefined") {
        return;
    }
    var whatToPanTo = (_UserMarkerNewPosition) ? _UserMarkerNewPosition : _UserMarkerPosition;
    _Map.panTo(whatToPanTo); 
};
```

if it is not, exit out.

Comment: @Jack I tested it but for working need to write undefined like this: 'undefined' and will work perfectly! is there any other mistake you think?

Comment: I forgot the quotes, and if @Jack was nice, Jack would have edited it instead of being snarky. ;) That is what happens when you answer a question before your first cup of coffee.

Comment: Didn't mean to be snarky, I'm on a mobile device and don't really trust editing posts with it :)

Comment: @gerti once you gain 3k rep you don't have that limitation :)

Comment: @Jack, at first I was like what in the world are you talking about than I took a sip of my freshly brewed coffee and saw the mistake. :) I first thought I did the ternary wrong.